# How do you cite a quote that is broken up into two parts?

Tags: citations

If I have one quote but I broke it up into two separate sections in my essay, how would I cite it? Even though they're the same quote would I need to cite it twice? I know an ibid would work but I'm using MLA.

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on the context of the citations. If they're separated in different parts of the essay with other citations in between, you'd cite them the same in both instances, e.g.,

> and then there's "blah blah" (Jones 59)
>
> ...
>
> and then there's "yah yah" (Jones 59).

If, however, there are no intervening citations, it is sufficient to just give a page number citation on the second instance if you've established in the text that these are continued citations from the same source.

> and then there's "blah blah" (Jones 59)
>
> ...
>
> and then there's "yah yah" (59).

See https://style.mla.org/same-source-multiple-paragraphs/

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

The first time you use the quote, put "__ " said __ source __ (insert footnote w/reference) and then the second time use use it, "__" said/stated/wrote __ source __ see (insert same footnote as first time ref.)

Example: If i were writing an essay on the properties of Apples and comparing them to windows computers, I could use the following quote "Apples are very popular and allow your computer to be compatible with other peoples' apple computers, but windows have better processing systems."

In P1: I would say, "Apples are very popular and allow your computer to be compatible with other peoples' apple computers" says fakenews.com^

In P2: fakenews.com stated "windows have better processing systems." see^.

Comment: Good answer, but where is your source?